# How to create and access arraylist(in java) of item rows from mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I have a clas BookBean, where I have the fields from database: id, title and author. I want to create an ArrayList bookList of BookBean type, where to get each row from database. For example, bookList[0] should point to the first row from database: id=1, title=first title, author=first author.

I have tried declaring a BookBean variable and an ArrayList:

```
static ArrayList<BookBean> listBooks = new ArrayList<>();
static BookBean bookBean = new BookBean(1,"title", "author");
```

This is my function where I get items from database. I can access the items inside the ResultSet search, but not outside it. How can I store the items into the arraylist properly?

```
public static void generateBookList(){
        try {
            Connection connection = ConnectToDatabase.createConnection();
            if (connection != null) {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from book ");
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    bookBean.setId(resultSet.getInt("id_book"));
                    bookBean.setTitle(resultSet.getString("title"));
                    bookBean.setAuthor(resultSet.getString("author"));
                    listBooks.add(bookBean);

                    System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getId());
                    System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getTitle());
                    System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getAuthor());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your list must contain **several** books. Not just one. So you need to **create** a **new** book at each iteration of your loop, and ad this new book in the list (which probably shouldn't be static either, but instead created and returned by your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new OBJECT of `BookBean` everytime you insert into ArrayList.

```
public static void generateBookList(){
        try {
            Connection connection = ConnectToDatabase.createConnection();
            if (connection != null) {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from book ");
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    //You are actually using the same object again and again.
                    // Following line is important.
                    BookBean x = new BookBean(resultSet.getInt("id_book"), resultSet.getString("title"), resultSet.getString("author"));
                    listBooks.add(x);

                    System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getId());
                    System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getTitle());
                    System.out.println(listBooks.get(0).getAuthor());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```